# Are two functions $f$ and $g$ with linear independent derivatives neccessarily linearly independent and vice versa?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Suppose that there exists functions $f$ and $g$ defined on the real numbers and differentiable everywhere. If their derivatives $f'$ and $g'$ are linearly independent on some nonzero interval then are $f$ and $g$ linearly independent on the same interval? Similarly if $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent then are $f'$ and $g'$ linearly independent?

I am trying to determine whether it might be more efficient to prove that^ then to prove $f$ and $g$ have linearly independent derivatives for every $f$ and $g$ I can think of.

Edit: I did heavily alter this question. However, the questions are $100$% equivalent. It is just that using the term "linear independent" rather than "there does not exist real numbers $c$ and $d$..." is easier to read and much clearer.

Comment: Are $f\colon x\mapsto x^2$ and $g\colon x\mapsto 0$ linearly independent?

Comment: Indeed. Then the answer to your question is no, since they are a counterexample..

Comment: They are. The answer points this out, and gives a similar counterexample; have you read it? your question asks for both c and d non zero, which leads to counter examples. (Both non zero and not both zero are not the same thing.)

Comment: ?! Are you kidding me? If you know your question is poorly phrased and wrong because of that, edit it. Don't be aggressive and pretend the people pointing it out made a mistake.

Comment: "$(c,d)\neq(0,0)$" or "not $c$ and $d$ both zero" would be the correct way to capture what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For instance, $f=0$ and $g(x)=x$ are linearly dependent (because $f+0g=0$), yet if $cf'(x)+dg'(x)=0$ for any $x$, then $d=0$.

On the other hand, if you meant "there aren't $c,d$ which are not both zero" rather than "there aren't $c,d$ which are both non-zero", then the implication is true (*on the interval of interest*), because linear independence of the derivatives means that no linear combination of the functions by non-trivial coefficients can be *constant*. Of course, said technique wouldn't manage to prove that, say, $\arctan$ and $\operatorname{arccot}$ are linearly independent.